# <class '_pickle.UnpicklingError'> - invalid load key, '\x00' in ZMQ socket.recv_pyobj()

Tags: tcp, pickle, pyzmq

I have referred related queries and unable to fix the above error. I'm running server & client python object sharing between two separate process. Client needs to send dict or tuple to server.
I have tried with changing protocol into pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL and pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL. still the issue is not resolved...but out can print the dict which i sent.

SERVER CODE:

```
import zmq
import socket
import sys
import datetime
import pickle

def errorhandling(name: str, msg: str) -> None:
        """
        To handle Error in the API and Strategies, if you call this
        """
        try:
            print(f" {datetime.datetime.now().time()}| ERROR |{name} | {msg} | {sys.exc_info()[0]} -"
                  f" {sys.exc_info()[1]} | Line No:{sys.exc_info()[2].tb_lineno}")
                          
        except Exception as e:
            print("error", f" {name} | ErrorHandlingError - {e}")

ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

ordcontext = zmq.Context()
ordsocket = ordcontext.socket(zmq.XREP)
ordsocket.bind(f"tcp://{ip}:7712")

def ordersocket():
    print("Order socket Running")
    while True:
        try:
            #orddata = self.ordsocket.recv().decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
            orddata = ordsocket.recv_pyobj()
            #orddata2 = pickle.loads(orddata)
            print(orddata)
        except Exception:
            errorhandling(name="ordername",
                          msg="ordersocket")
                
    print("Order socket NOT Running")
            
ordersocket()
```

CLIENT CODE:

```
import zmq
import time
import socket
import pickle
ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
orcontext = zmq.Context()
orsocket = orcontext.socket(zmq.XREQ)
orsocket.connect(f"tcp://{ip}:7712")

def sendorder():
    while True:
        data = {"A": "Nameofstg", "LTP": 1200, "QTY":200, "SS":"Now", "PP":230}
        orsocket.send_pyobj(obj=data,protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        time.sleep(3)
        
sendorder()
```

ERROR (with printing statement):

```
<class '_pickle.UnpicklingError'> - invalid load key, '\x00'.
```

11:34:49.665037| ERROR |ordername | ordersocket | <class '_pickle.UnpicklingError'> - invalid load key, '\x00'. | Line No:35
{'A': 'Nameofstg', 'LTP': 1200, 'QTY': 200, 'SS': 'Now', 'PP': 230}

Comment: Can someone reply to query...help me out

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the problem in your code, but try the code below, it works. You actually don't need `pickle`, `socket.send_pyobj` can be used to send objects like a dictionary.

Assume `master.py` and `worker.py` are under the same `dir`.

`master.py`

```
import zmq
import sys
import pexpect 
from getpass import getuser
from socket import gethostname


python = sys.executable
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
port = socket.bind_to_random_port("tcp://*")
server_host = gethostname()
server_socket = "%s:%s" % (server_host, port)

worker_command = "%s -m worker" % python + " %i " + server_socket
children = []
for ind in range(4):
    child = pexpect.spawn(worker_command % ind)
    children.append(child)
           
active = 4
while True:
    message = socket.recv_pyobj()
    print(message)
    socket.send_pyobj('task done')
    active -= 1
    if active == 0:
        break
```

and `worker.py`

```
import os
import sys
import zmq
from socket import gethostname

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
      
      
    import logging

    logging.basicConfig(filename = f"log")
    try:
        server_socket = sys.argv[-1]
        worker_id = int(sys.argv[-2])
        port_number = int(server_socket.split(':')[-1])
        
        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
        socket.connect('tcp://%s' % server_socket)
        
        data = {"A": "Nameofstg_%i" % worker_id}
        socket.send_pyobj(data)
        socket.recv_pyobj()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
```

As you can see by running `python master.py`, the dictionaries sent by the four workers can be successfully received by the master, and actually, you don't need `pickle` since we use `socket.send_pyobj`.

You might also note that in `worker.py`, I use `logging.basicConfig(filename = f"log")`. In doing so, the `Exception` in the worker process can be caught.

Comment: @ManjunathanVenkatesan Hi Manjunathan Venkatesan, have your problem been resolved?